# How to access props in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```
class Iframe extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      iFrameHeight: '0px',
    }
    this.iFrameUrl = props.url
  }
```

I want to access to access the props within the render function which looks like this:

```
render (props) {
  return (
    <iframe
      style={{width: '100%', height: this.state.iFrameHeight, overflow: 'visible'}}
      onLoad={() => {
        const obj = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
        this.setState({
          'iFrameHeight': obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'
        })
      }}
      ref='iframe'
      src={props.url}
      width='100%'
      scrolling='no'
      frameBorder='0'
      sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts'
    />
  )
}
```

I am getting the src URL for the iframe from the props. What's the correct way to access the props within the render's return method?

Comment: `this.props.propName` should be sufficent

Answer (score 1):

You just use `this.props`, if you want to use it inside the JSX, make sure  to wrap it with curly braces.

```
 render () {
      console.log(this.props) // this is how to use props inside render method
      return (
        <iframe
          style={{width: '100%', height: this.state.iFrameHeight, overflow: 'visible'}}
          onLoad={() => {
            const obj = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
            this.setState({
              'iFrameHeight': obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'
            })
          }}
          ref='iframe'
          src={props.url}
          width='100%'
          scrolling='no'
          frameBorder='0'
          sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts'
        />
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are accepting props in the constructor, you need to pass it to the parent component as well. (In this case `React.Component`)

```
class Iframe extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
   super(props);
   ...
 }
```

Once that's in place, you can refer to props any time in any of your component functions/life-cycle hooks/render method by simple using

`this.props.url     //any key in your prop`

So now, in your constructor use this.props.url

```
constructor (props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     iFrameHeight: '0px',
   }
   this.iFrameUrl = this.props.url    
}
```

If you want to modify the url, then use `this.frameUrl` in `render` method, else you can directly use `this.props.url` in your `render` method.